# Calcular ao Selecionar a Opção Na Classe Enum

Tags: javafx

Boa Tarde!!... Estou com a seguinte dúvida... tenho uma classe Enum e nela dentro de cada "opção" executo um cálculo ao selecionar... Como faria fara esse cálculo ser executado e assim, eu ter um resultado?

veja o trecho do código:

```
public enum CoeficienteA implements EquacaoCamFinaInterface {

Polinomial {

            @Override
            public double calcular(Fruto fruto) {//Poli

                double a;
                a = fruto.getA1() + fruto.getA2() * fruto.getCondicao().getTempeSgm() + fruto.getA3() * Math.pow(fruto.getCondicao().getTempeSgm(), 2) + fruto.getA4() * Math.pow(fruto.getCondicao().getTempeSgm(), 3)
                + fruto.getA5() * Math.pow(fruto.getCondicao().getTempeSgm(), 4) + fruto.getA6() * Math.pow(fruto.getCondicao().getTempeSgm(), 5) + fruto.getA7() * Math.pow(fruto.getCondicao().getTempeSgm(), 6)
                + fruto.getA8() * Math.pow(fruto.getCondicao().getTempeSgm(), 7);
                return a;
            }
        },
Exponencial {
            @Override
            public double calcular(Fruto fruto) {
                double a;
                a = fruto.getA1() + Math.exp(-fruto.getA2() * fruto.getCondicao().getTempeSgm());
                return a;
            }
        };
```

}

Preciso que quando eu selecionar um item do combobox ele chame o método, tentei usar o evento que segue abaixo porém dá erro, pois ele não recohece a classe coeficienteA (CoeficienteA newValue) como um objeto, preciso que ele execute quando eu selecionar, pois preciso do dado retornado pela função acima.

```
 comboboxCoefA.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {


        public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, CoeficienteA newValue) {
            newValue.Exponencial.calcular(fruto);
        }


        }


    });
```

Comment: Preciso que quando eu selecionar um item do combobox ele chame um método, que execute só quando eu selecionar, pois preciso do dado retornado pela função.

Answer (score 0):

Se você está usando FXML é bem simples, basta adicionar o método que você deseja no evento onAction do ComboBox, ele será executado sempre que for selecionado algum item no Combo.

O exemplo abaixo vai exibir o novo valor selecionado do combo:

```
@FXML
public void comboOnAction() {
    System.out.println(combo.getValue());
}
```

Lembrando de adicionar no FXML o metodo acima.

Caso não use FXML você pode setar no combo o evento onAction.
O exemplo abaixo tem o mesmo resultado que o de cima:

```
combo.setOnAction(new EventHandler<Event>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(Event event) {
                System.out.println(combo.getValue());
            }

        });
```

Se estiver usando java 8 podes utilizar também o lambda para fazer isso:

```
combo.setOnAction(event -> {
            System.out.println(combo.getValue());
        });
```